# How to clear comments and intermediate whitespace in a string containing a C function declaration?

Tags: c++, parsing, function, comments, removing-whitespace

In my program, written in C++, I need to take a set of strings, each containing the declaration of a C function, and perform a number of operations on them.

One of the operations is to compare whether one function is equal to another. To do that I plan to just prune away comments and intermediate whitespace which has no effect on the semantics of the function and then do a string comparison. However, I would like to retain whitespace within a string as removing that would change the output produced by the function.

I could write some code which iterates over the string characters and enters "string mode" whenever a quote (`"`) is encountered and recognize escaped quotes, but I wonder if there is any better way of doing this. An idea is to use a full-fledged C parser, run it over the function string, ignore all comments and excessive whitespace, and then convert the AST back to a string again. But looking around at some C parser I get the feeling that most are a bitch to integrate with my source code (prove me wrong if I am). Perhaps I could try to use `yacc` or something and use an existing C grammar and implement the parser myself...

So, any ideas on the best way to do this?

### EDIT:

The program I'm writing takes an abstract model and converts it into C code. The model consists of a graph, where the nodes may or may not contain segments of C code (more precisely, a C function definition where its execution must be completely deterministic (i.e. no global state) and no memory operations are allowed). The program does pattern matching on the graph and merges and splits certain nodes who adhere to these patterns. However, these operations can only be performed if the nodes exhibit the same functionality (i.e. if their C function definitions are the same). This "checking that they are the same" will be done by simply comparing the strings which contain the C function declarations. If they are character-by-character identical, then they are equal.

Due to the nature of how the models are generated, this is quite a reasonable method of comparison *provided* that the comments and excess whitespace is removed as this is the only factor that may differ. This is the problem I'm facing -- how to do this with minimal amount of implementation effort?

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by *compare whether one function is equal to another* ? With a suitably precise meaning, that problem is known to be **undecidable**!

You did not tell what your program is really doing. Parsing all real C programs correctly is not trivial (because the C language syntax and semantics is not that simple!).

Did you consider using existing tools or libraries to help you? [LLVM Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) is a possibility, or extending [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) thru plugins, or even better with extensions coded in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/).

But we cannot help you more without understanding your real goal. And parsing C code is probably more complex than what you imagine.

Comment: I've extended my original question with an explanation of what my program is doing. Yes, I have considered using an existing tool or library as parsing C is indeed very difficult. However, as I only need to do syntactic checking on a single C function and not an entire program, there's also the idea of writing my own grammar.

Comment: I don't understand well how parsing a single C function makes sense for you. A single C function can call inline functions, and more importantly it depends upon `struct`, `union`, `enum` declarations which can be complex. I still think that taking advantage of an existing tool (eg extending GCC, notably with MELT) is simpler. If you really want to avoid parsing whole files (but what's the point) you might generate C code containing the minimal stuff, and have the compiler eat it.

Comment: Nowhere have I stated that I need to _compile_ the code; I simply need to _parse_ it and check that it is syntactically valid. The actual compiling is done at a later stage that I need not concern myself with. Also, the functionality allowed in the C function is restricted (e.g. memory allocation and function calls are not allowed). So, to _me_, it _does_ makes sense to parse a single C function.

Comment: You can use `gcc` to deal with the code without doing all. In particular, if you extend it by MELT, you would add a pass inside it, and that pass could stop the compilation process. Still, parsing a single C function is not that simple in practice (macros, complexity of the C language, prerequisites on declarations, ...)

Comment: And how would you check that a C function don't do any function call or malloc? It can use macros which are syntactically function-like...

Comment: Well, for one thing, macros and preprocessor commands aren't allowed either. And the problem of using an existing compiler is that it would fail on the input as it's not a complete program declaration (only a function declaration).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can get away with simple island grammar removing comments, string literals, and collapsing white spaces (tabs, '\n'). Since I'm working with AXE<sup>†</sup>, I wrote a quick grammar<sup>‡</sup> for you. You can write a similar set of rules using Boost.Spirit.

```
#include <axe.h>
#include <string>

template<class I>
std::string clean_text(I i1, I i2)
{
    // rules for non-recursive comments, and no line continuation
    auto endl = axe::r_lit('\n');
    auto c_comment = "/*" & axe::r_find(axe::r_lit("*/"));
    auto cpp_comment = "//" & axe::r_find(endl);
    auto comment = c_comment | cpp_comment;

    // rules for string literals
    auto esc_backslash = axe::r_lit("\\\\");
    auto esc_quote = axe::r_lit("\\\"");
    auto string_literal = '"' & *(*(axe::r_any() - esc_backslash - esc_quote) 
        & *(esc_backslash | esc_quote)) & '"';

    auto space = axe::r_any(" \t\n");
    auto dont_care = *(axe::r_any() - comment - string_literal - space);

    std::string result;
    // semantic actions
    // append everything matched
    auto append_all = axe::e_ref([&](I i1, I i2) { if(i1 != i2) result += std::string(i1, i2); });
    // append a single space
    auto append_space = axe::e_ref([&](I i1, I i2) { if(i1 != i2) result += ' '; });

    // island grammar for text
    auto text = *(dont_care >> append_all 
        & *comment
        & *string_literal >> append_all
        & *(space % comment) >> append_space)
        & axe::r_end();

    if(text(i1, i2).matched)
        return result;
    else
        throw "error";
}
```

So now you can do the text cleaning:

```
std::string text; // this is your function
text = clean_text(text.begin(), text.end());
```

You might also need to create rules for superfluous ';', empty blocks {}, and alike. You might also need to merge string literals. How far you need to go depends on the way the functions were generated, you may end up writing a sizable portion of C grammar.

<sup>†</sup> AXE library is soon to be released under boost license.
<sup>‡</sup> I didn't test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your C functions that you want to parse are not as general (in their textual form, and also as parsed by a real compiler) as we are guessing.

You might consider doing things **the other way round**:

It could make sense to **define a small domain specific language** (it could have a syntax much simpler to parse than C) and instead of parsing C code, doing it the other way: The user would use your DSL, and **your tool would generate C code** (to be compiled at a later stage by your usual C compiler) **from your DSL**.

Your DSL could actually be the description of *your abstract model* mixed with more procedural parts which are translated to C functions. Since the C functions you care about are quite specific, the DSL generating them could be small.

(Think that many parser generators like ANTLR or YACC or Bison are build on a similar idea).

I actually did something quite similar in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (read notably my [DSL2011 paper](http://gcc-melt.org/MELT-Starynkevitch-DSL2011.pdf)). You might find some useful tricks about designing a DSL translated to C.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a DSL as the input models are generated  from SystemC code. What I could do, however, is allow a subset from C, but I suspect that would still be quite cumbersome.